# How to use properly EntityRepository instances?

Tags: mikro-orm

The documentation stresses that I should use a new `EntityManager` for each request and there's even a middleware for automatically generating it or alternatively I can use `em.fork()`. So far so good.

The `EntityRepository` is a great way to make the code readable. I could not find anything in the documentation about how they relate to `EntityManager` instances. The `express-ts-example-app` example uses single instances of repositories and the `RequestContext` middleware. This suggests that there is some under-the-hood magic that finds the correct `EntityManager` instances at least with the `RequestContext`. Is it really so?

Also, if I fork the EM manually can it still find the right one? Consider the following example:

```
(async () => {
  DI.orm = await MikroORM.init();
  DI.em = DI.orm.em;
  DI.companyRepository = DI.orm.em.getRepository(Company);
  DI.invoiceRepository = DI.orm.em.getRepository(Invoice);
  ...
  fetchInvoices(em.fork());
}

async function fetchInvoices(em) {
  for (const company of await DI.companyRepository.findAll()) {
    fetchInvoicesOfACompany(company, em.fork())
  }
}

async function fetchInvoicesOfACompany(company, em) {
  let done = false;
  while (!done) {
    const invoice = await getNextInvoice(company.taxnumber, company.lastInvoice);
    if ( invoice ) {
      DI.invoiceRepository.persist(invoice);
      company.lastInvoice = invoice.id;
      em.flush();
    } else {
      done = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Does the `DI.invoiceRepository.persist()` in `fetchInvoicesOfACompany()` use the right EM instance? If not, what should I do?

Also, if I'm not mistaken, the `em.flush()` in `fetchInvoicesOfACompany()` does not update company, since that belongs to another EM - how should I handle situations like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, repository is just a thin layer on top of EM (an extension point if you want), that bares the entity name so you don't have to pass it to the first parameter of EM method (e.g. `em.find(Ent, ...)` vs `repo.find(...)`.

Then the contexts - you need a dedicated context for each request, so it has its own identity map. If you use `RequestContext` helper, the context is created and saved via `domain` API. Thanks to this, all the methods that are executed inside the domain handler will use the right instance automatically - this happens in the `em.getContext()` method, that first checks the `RequestContext` helper.

https://mikro-orm.io/docs/identity-map/#requestcontext-helper-for-di-containers

Check the tests for better understanding of how it works:

https://github.com/mikro-orm/mikro-orm/blob/master/tests/RequestContext.test.ts

So if you use repositories, with `RequestContext` helper it will work just fine as the singleton repository instance will use the singleton EM instance that will then use the right request based instance via `em.getContext()` where approapriate.

But if you use manual forking instead, you are responsible use the right repository instance - each EM fork will have its own one. So in this case you can't use a singleton, you need to do `forkedEm.getRepository(Ent)`.

Btw alternatively you can also use `AsyncLocalStorage` which is faster (and not deprecated), if you are on node 12+. The `RequestContext` helper implementation will use ALS in v5, as node 12+ will be requried.

https://mikro-orm.io/docs/async-local-storage

Another thing you could do is to use the `RequestContext` helper manually instead of via middlewares - something like the following:

```
(async () => {
  DI.orm = await MikroORM.init();
  DI.em = DI.orm.em;
  DI.companyRepository = DI.orm.em.getRepository(Company);
  DI.invoiceRepository = DI.orm.em.getRepository(Invoice);
...
  await RequestContext.createAsync(DI.em, async () => {
    await fetchInvoices();
  })
});

async function fetchInvoices() {
  for (const company of await DI.companyRepository.findAll()) {
    await fetchInvoicesOfACompany(company)
  }
}

async function fetchInvoicesOfACompany(company) {
  let done = false;

  while (!done) {
    const invoice = await getNextInvoice(company.taxnumber, company.lastInvoice);
    
    if (invoice) {
      company.lastInvoice = invoice; // passing entity instance, no need to persist as `company` is managed entity and this change will be cascaded
      await DI.em.flush();
    } else {
      done = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this splendid explanation!
Just a little clarification: does the `DI.em.flush()` at the end write the invoice to the DB too?

Comment: It will always flush only what it sees in its context (so what was loading with that fork, or what was persisted to it). So in my example that uses the `RequestContext` helper, it will flush the changes as it will use the right fork. In your example it would actually also probably flush correctly, as you loaded the company entity with the same `em` as you are flushing. Btw you have another problem there - just calling `em.persist` will not make the PK available, flush is needed. You should pass the entity instance (using a m:1 or something) so it can be done automatically during flush.